# Ruby form parameters are null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, post, null

I'm completely newbie to ruby, and my boss put me to develop a new module in a ruby system.

I just need to create a new page in the dashboard to create some "Service Plans", is just a name, discount percentage and a list of services. I looked how they created other pages and tried to copy them.

My page is almost EXACTLY the New Professionals page. I created a form.haml, a model, a controller and a Plan Form class (they use it to validate the form.)

But when I try to use some parameters in the Plan Form class, they are just nil!

Here is my code:

[image: Plan Class]
[image: Plan Controller]
[image: My partial Form.haml]
[image: My PlanForm Class where the posted date should be validated]
[image: My console with the Result and messages]
[image: The rest of result, and we can see that in the line Parameters: the services id's are there!!]

Images legends:   1 - My Plan Class   2 - My Plan Controller  3 - My partial _form haml  4 - My Plan Form Class where the posted date should be validated and saved.  5 - My console with the Result and messages   6 - The rest of result. Look at parameters line: the  services id's are there! > how can I access them?

My questions are:  First: My classes are exactly the same, why doesn't it work?

Second: How can I access the Parameters inside the Plan Form class?

Third: Are there any other better way to do that?

Sorry for the mistakes/wrong format, is my first question here.

Comment: Can you try to format the question to give relevant details which are easy to grasp. I dont think may are able to get the problem you are facing. May be the view code, how you are making the request and how you are accessing your params will help.

Comment: I was editing it. I don't know why but stackoverflow understood everything as text.  Check if it's ok now.

Comment: What code is in your `plan_params` method?

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, this whole process is a lot easier if you put text in your question rather than images.

Comment: There is exactly what I need: 

 {"name"=>"teste 3", "discount"=>"12", "services"=>["", "11", "6", "4", "5", "25", "24", "23", "26"]}

I just don't know how to access @form.params, because inside my PlanForm class it doesn't exist!

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why but in my PlanForm class I need to use just @services and not self.services. It can seems obvious since I have a attr_accessor @services declared, but in ALL other classes in the project they use like self.services and it works. Plus, if I print self.inspect.to_s I can see that there is a services object inside self object, but if I use it like self.services, or self[:services] or anything, it gets null.

So, I'm just using @services now and it is working.

Thanks.